# Qlikview - Scatter chart dot colors dimension setup not working

Tags: qlikview

I have some data that I want to display in scatter chart. I have the following two dimensions:

**Dimension1**: This is each record in the table - say unique id for each row. So the number of dots should be equal to number of records.

**Dimension2**: This is a combination of 2 columns. `tp` and `vc`. Colors of each dot is based on these 2 columns.

```
   tp    vc
1  a     1 
2  b     2 
3  c     1
```

So there will be dots of 3 colors based on the above `tp` and `vc` combinations. Then there are 3 expressions representing X and Y and Size of dot. I am not sure how to configure the dimensions to achieve the goal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need a calculated dimmension which is the concatanation expression defined as `=tp & vc` in your case.

Then this will be your single dimmension. Then your `x`,`y`,`size` expressions make up the remaining requirements for this chart.

This will give you three colors, one for each unique record combination and they will be labled `a1` and `b2` and `c1`.

```
id      tp      vc      x       y       size
1   |   a   |   1   |   3   |   5   |   7
2   |   b   |   2   |   1   |   2   |   10
3   |   c   |   1   |   9   |   5   |   5
```

[image]